# SQL Join returns only one record

Tags: mysql, database, join, count

I'm writing a query whereby I'm trying to count the total number of records in report and assignment table, whiles at the same time retrieving information from the main table group. Group has a primary key id which is saved in the other tables as gid. This is the query:

```
SELECT  `group`.`id` AS `gid`
        , `group`.`name` AS `g_name`
        , COUNT(`report`.`id`) AS `reports` 
FROM    `group` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `report` ON `report`.`gid` = `group`.`id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment` ON `assignment`.`gid` = `group`.`id` 
WHERE   `group`.`active` = 0 
ORDER BY 
        `group`.`name`;
```

My problem is whenever I execute this only one record is returned even if theirs multiple groups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS? This won't even parse in SQL Server.

Comment: Not gonna downvote, but I'd like to give a -5 for naming a table "group."  At least use brackets around it...please.

Comment: it's mysql and it doesn't because someone just edited it

Comment: I didnt do it someone just changed it

Comment: is your enter/new line key broken?

Comment: @Parham All I did was reformat it, because it's unreadable on a single line. Please can you reformat it again so it is readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your query is far from correct :) First of all, you should not have aggregated functions (in this case `count`) without a `group by` clause. Now, even if you have that clause the query will summarize information and you want both: the detail and a summary in the same query. I'd recommend 2 separate queries to retrieve this information, but if you want information mixed in only one query (the detail and also the "total number of records in report and assignment table") try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `group`.id AS gid, 
    `group`.name AS g_name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from report) as ReportTotalCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from assignment) as AssignmentTotalCount,
FROM `group`
WHERE `group`.`active` = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN report ON report.gid = `group`.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN assignment ON assignment.gid = `group`.id
ORDER BY `group`.name;
```

I whish I could understand exactly what you're looking for but this might give you an idea on how to get the result you expect.

Comment: I was trying to get the total number of reports submitted by a group and the total number of assignments they have been assigned by admin. And the active means if the group is still working together

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything obvious in your query that would limit it to returning one record.

You are going to have to break it up to see where the problem is against your existing data.

So how many groups where acitive = 0, ahow many with a corresponding assignment record, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help:

```
SELECT 
    groupid, 
    groupname, 
    reports,
    assignments,
FROM 
(SELECT group.id, group.name, COUNT(*) AS reports from group
    INNER JOIN report ON (report.gid = group.id) 
    WHERE group.active = 0
    GROUP BY group.id ) AS ReportForGroup
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT group.id AS groupid, group.name AS groupname, COUNT(*) AS assignments from group
    INNER JOIN assignmentON (assignment.gid = group.id) 
    WHERE group.active = 0
    GROUP BY group.id ) AS AssignmentForGroup   
    ON (ReportForGroup.groupid = AssignmentForGroup.groupid)
ORDER BY groupname;
```

I'm can't check it so if LEFT JOIN returns to COUNT(*) 0 or 1. if it returns 0 just change the INNERs to LEFTs and use INNER JOIN between the two queries